# Remove (text based) Linux Logo that comes after booting

Tags: linux, boot

I ported Petalinux on Zynq board by Xilinx. I am having a log message as shown below:

```
.
.
.
.
.[Wed Feb 12 14:55:44.166 2014]      Hash algo:    sha1
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:44.166 2014]      Hash value:   266e39ed71a93229a26f0cf7e9f5317b64c2e407
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:44.166 2014]    Verifying Hash Integrity ... crc32+ sha1+ OK
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:44.166 2014]    Booting using the fdt blob at 0x14bafcc
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:44.169 2014]    Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:44.555 2014]    Loading Device Tree to 07ffa000, end 07fffb98 ... OK
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:44.555 2014] 
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:44.555 2014] Starting kernel ...
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:44.555 2014] 
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:45.223 2014] INIT: version 2.88 booting
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:45.511 2014] Starting Bootlog daemon: bootlogd.
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:45.553 2014] Creating /dev/flash/* device nodes
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:45.957 2014] Configuring network interfaces... ifconfig: socket: Address family not supported by protocol
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:46.003 2014] ifconfig: socket: Address family not supported by protocol
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:46.015 2014] starting Busybox inet Daemon: inetd... done.
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:46.025 2014] Starting uWeb server:
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:46.052 2014] petalinux <error> (httpd): Failed to create server socket: Address family not supported by protocol
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:46.062 2014] INIT: Entering runlevel: 5
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:46.076 2014] Stopping Bootlog daemon: bootlogd.
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.122 2014] 
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.122 2014]  _____       _           _      _
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.122 2014] | ___ \     | |         | |    (_)
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.122 2014] | |_/ / ___ | |_   __ _ | |     _  _ __   _   _ __  __
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.122 2014] |  __/ / _ \| __| / _` || |    | || '_ \ | | | |\ \/ /
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.122 2014] | |   |  __/| |_ | (_| || |____| || | | || |_| | >  <
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.122 2014] \_|    \___| \__| \__,_|\_____/|_||_| |_| \__,_|/_/\_\
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.122 2014] 
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.122 2014] PetaLinux v2013.10 (Yocto 1.4) Xilinx-ZC702-14_7 ttyPS0
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.122 2014] 
[Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.136 2014] Xilinx-ZC702-14_7 login: root
```

at time stamp [Wed Feb 12 14:55:47.122 2014], there is a big size logo of petalinux. I have seen such logos on many flavors including `Angstrom Linux`. How do we remove such Logos, which file is to be edited?

Answer (score 3):

usually this logo is created by the `linuxlogo` init-script (e.g. `/etc/init.d/linuxlogo`).

you can customize it via `/etc/linux_logo.conf` (see `man linuxlogo`), or disable it by disabling the init-script.

but why do you want to suppress credits to *PetaLinux*?

Comment: The reason that I am suppressing it is because the end application will not have a display. In fact I event don't need login prompt, which I will ask as separate question after my research is over.

Comment: I could not find such a file anywhere. Even I tried my RHEL 6 machine , but no such file exist. But for  graphics logo , I can see I have to edit files in /usr/src/linux/drivers/video/logo/ , but I want text based logos.

Comment: @user2799508 if your device does not have a display, why do you care at all about what is (not) displayed?

Comment: Because I have to remove everything which is useless for my application and thus save on resources